# How can I get a list of package locations from a PIP requirements file?

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to generate a list from PIP, to the actual resources in the file?  For instance, if I had a requirements file with

```
Flask
Flask-Login
```

I would like to get output something like:

```
Name: Flask
Version: 0.10.1
Summary: A microframework based on Werkzeug, Jinja2 and good intentions
Home-page: http://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/

Name: Flask-Login
Version: 0.3.2
Summary: User session management for Flask
Home-page: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login
```

I found that information from pip show, but would like it to run on all the requirements that I have in the requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up packages in the PyPI using the [XMLRPC API](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc):

```
try:
    import xmlrpclib  # Python 2
except ImportError:
    import xmlrpc.client as xmlrpclib  # Python 3

pypi = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://pypi.python.org/pypi')

package_name = "Flask-Login"

packages = pypi.search({"name": package_name})
package = next(package for package in packages if package["name"] == package_name)
release_data = pypi.release_data(package_name, package["version"])

print(package_name)
print(package["version"])
print(release_data["summary"])
print(release_data["home_page"])
```

Prints:

```
Flask-Login
0.3.0
User session management for Flask
https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login
```

Comment: this seems perfect, trying now.

Comment: This is great, very helpful.  I made a complete script from it, in case anyone is interested, it's here: https://gist.github.com/nycynik/dfdfb220186716e8cd008ae77ffe47e5